# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded in CipherInputStream

Tags: java, cryptography, java-security

This question was probably asked already, but since I'm having a hard time understanding cryptography, and especially key handling, I'm not sure how to handle this exception, nor where / how to find the solution.

I'm trying to write and read objects to and from an encrypted file.
For that purpose I've wrapped a CipherInputStream under a DataInputStream.

I'm getting the BadPadding exception, which probably means I'm doing something wrong with the key.

Please help me.

Main.java:

```
package main;

import java.util.Arrays;

import io.Io;

public class Main {
    static final String FIRST_TEXT_TO_CRYPTO = "First text";
    static final boolean BOOLEAN_CRYPTO = true;
    static final String SECOND_TEXT_TO_CRYPTO = "First text";
    static final String KEY = "key123";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Io.encryptAndWriteAll(Arrays.asList(new Stuff(FIRST_TEXT_TO_CRYPTO, BOOLEAN_CRYPTO, SECOND_TEXT_TO_CRYPTO)),
                KEY);

        for (Stuff stuff : Io.readAndDecryptAllFromLocation(KEY)) {
            System.out.println(stuff);
        }
    }
}
```

Stuff.java

```
package main;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Stuff {
    SimpleStringProperty firstString = new SimpleStringProperty(), secondString = new SimpleStringProperty();
    SimpleBooleanProperty bool = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public Stuff(String firstString, boolean bool, String secondString) {
        this.firstString.set(firstString);
        this.secondString.set(secondString);
        this.bool.set(bool);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("FirstString: %s; Boolean: %B; SecondString: %s", getFirstString(), isBool(),
                getSecondString());
    }

    public final SimpleStringProperty firstStringProperty() {
        return this.firstString;
    }

    public final String getFirstString() {
        return this.firstStringProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFirstString(final String firstString) {
        this.firstStringProperty().set(firstString);
    }

    public final SimpleStringProperty secondStringProperty() {
        return this.secondString;
    }

    public final String getSecondString() {
        return this.secondStringProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSecondString(final String secondString) {
        this.secondStringProperty().set(secondString);
    }

    public final SimpleBooleanProperty boolProperty() {
        return this.bool;
    }

    public final boolean isBool() {
        return this.boolProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setBool(final boolean bool) {
        this.boolProperty().set(bool);
    }

}
```

Io.java:

```
package io;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UTFDataFormatException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

import main.Stuff;

public class Io {
    private static final File FILE = new File("file.file");

    public static void encryptAndWriteAll(List<Stuff> stuffs, String key) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, new Crypto(key).getEncryptionCipher());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(cos)) {
            for (Stuff stuff : stuffs) {
                dos.writeUTF(stuff.getFirstString());
                dos.writeBoolean(stuff.isBool());
                dos.writeUTF(stuff.getSecondString());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Stuff> readAndDecryptAllFromLocation(String key) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILE);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, new Crypto(key).getDecryptionCipher());
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(cis)) {
            ArrayList<Stuff> stuffs = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                for (;;)
                    // The next line throws
                    // ("at io.Io.readAndDecryptAllFromLocation(Io.java:52)")
                    stuffs.add(new Stuff(dis.readUTF(), dis.readBoolean(), dis.readUTF()));
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                System.out.println("EOF");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UTFDataFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stuffs;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Crypto.java:

```
package io;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypto {

    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private byte[] paddedKey;

    public Crypto(String key) {
        paddedKey = addPaddingToKey(key);
    }

    private byte[] addPaddingToKey(String key) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            return Arrays.copyOf(digest.digest(key.getBytes()), 16);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Key getKey() {
        return new SecretKeySpec(paddedKey, ALGORITHM);
    }

    public Cipher getEncryptionCipher() {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey());
            return cipher;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Cipher getDecryptionCipher() {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey());
            return cipher;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:121)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:239)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at io.Io.readAndDecryptAllFromLocation(Io.java:52)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:975)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:833)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2048)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:118)
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve], IOW just the code required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using AES/CBC, Which would need IV parameter. If you have not specified IV parameter while encrypting a random IV would be generated and used.

You can randomly generate IV and prepend it to encrypted data, since IV need not need to be secret.

Comment: Better yet on encryption prepend the IV to the encrypted data, it does not need to be secret. That way it is available for decryption.

Comment: Not using a random IV is insecure, storing the IV and reusing it only works if the encryption/decryption is executed at the same location. So although you may have uncovered the issue, the solutions presented won't solve it (securely).

Comment: So, is it ok if I prepend the IV that is randomly generated each time the data is encrypted to the file? Or, how should I store the randomly generated IV?

Comment: Prefixing the IV is indeed the obvious and most common solution. The IV may (should) be send unencrypted. The IV is precisely one block size in size for CBC (and most other modes), so it's easy to retrieve it from the ciphertext.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes and zaph, Thanks for correcting me. I have updated my answer.